# Write new image (resource type) to another server with php?

Tags: php

have a nice day.
I got problem when trying to create an image from server A and write to server B, like follow (in PHP)

1. Create an new image from existing image on server A (jpeg - in Resource type).
2. Add some text to new image (still in resource type).
3. But i cannot save the image resource to file on server A (permission restricted, server A is not owned by me and do not allow to write image file).
4. So I going to write this resource to server B (owned by me).

But I don't know how to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to shift the operations for creating and modifying the image to Server B where you can save it directly?

Comment: Yes. May I grant some permission to allow server A write file (in resource type) to my server (B) if necessary; or use ftp account?. But I don't know how to do this..

Comment: If the image on server A is web-accessible, you can launch the script on server B and pull the image over into your script, add the text to it and write it out directly on server B.